# BAD sql query shows all id

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i have a problem with my sql and php code,  this is my sql table;

this is my php code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reclamation,etudiant WHERE status_recla = 'En attendant' AND id_ens IS NULL";
                                  $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                                  if($query){
                                    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) != 0 ){
                                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td style='width: 150px;'>".$row['nom_etud']." ".$row['prenom_etud']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td style='width: 150px;'>".$row['date_recla']."</td></td>";
                                        echo "<td style='width: 150px;'>".$row['Titre_recla']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td style='width: 150px;'>".$row['desc_recla']."</td>";
                                        echo "<td class='text-center align-middle' style='max-height: 60px;height: 60px;'><a class='btn btn-primary' type='button' style='background-color: limegreen;margin-right: 20px;' href='edit.php?accepteRecla=".$row['id_recla']."&idchef=".$id."'>Accepter</a><a class='btn btn-primary' type='button' style='background-color: var(--bs-red);' href='edit.php?refuseRecla=".$row['id_recla']."&idchef=".$id."'>Refuser</a></td>";
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                  else{
                                    echo mysqli_error($conn);
                                  }
                                 ?>
```

[image: this is my sql table]

And this is the results:
[image: Results]

As you can see i have only 1 row that contains all the conditions but the results show 3 rows with all the IDs
what should i change to get only one row with the respective ID not all IDs

Comment: There are two tables in query, `reclamation,etudiant` so this is cartesian join without condition. And I suppose in second table there are 3 rows

Comment: You'll need to rethink your query. You're doing an inner join (comma), but the join may not be what you're expecting or wanting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comma join without matching column condition in `WHERE` is equivalent to a `CROSS JOIN`. How about you change the comma join to `JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM reclamation JOIN etudiant 
 ON reclamation.column1 = etudiant.column1 WHERE status_recla = 'En attendant' AND id_ens IS NULL 
/*               ^^^                 ^^^          
replace each column1 with matching related column from both tables*/
```

[Learn more about MySQL join here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)